# Is it possible to WiFi-Direct and WiFi hotspot enabled at the same time?

Tags: android, wifi

Is it possible to WiFi-Direct and WiFi hotspot enabled at the same time?

I mean, I want to share my internet connection by enabling my WiFi hotspot and I want to send a photo to another Android device by using WiFi-Direct. Is it possible?

I can't enable WiFi and WiFi Hotspot at the same time my Android phone?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Isn't there any way? It arise for hardware reasons? I guess, WiFi hardware doesn't allow it, right?

Comment: @Ahmet.Ozlu I have the same doubt. Did you get any answer for this?

Comment: Your device has radio transmitters/receivers built in that provide you different types of signals such as wifi, Bluetooth, etc. When you turn on your hotspot, the radios that handle wifi change from a state that allows you to access another wifi radio to a mode that make YOU the provider of wifi. The wifi radios can't do both at the same time.